# How can I stop MySQL from running out of connections when using Spring Boot Live Reload? CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: "Too many connections"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

After a few code changes, Spring Boot gets into a funky state, and floods my console logs with stack traces saying it can't get a DB connection. How can I have Spring Boot avoid this problem with Live Reload? It works if I kill it and run it again with `mvn spring-boot:run` (but that takes longer).

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"

I have Spring DevTools installed in my `pom.xml` for live-reload.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

This is my `DataSource` upon startup. The default `testOnBorrow` is true.

> 2018-12-03 16:09:39.530  INFO 14804 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.s.TheApp       : DATASOURCE = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@72d10b82{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb?useSSL=false; username=root; validationQuery=/* ping */ SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; useStatementFacade=true; }

Comment: This could well be an issue caused by your code. Most time it is. Without seeing that we are rather hobbled when it comes to useful comment

Comment: How are you using JDBC--directly, `JdbcTemplate`, JPA?

Comment: I'm using MyBatis Mappers. I'm not using JDBC directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your pool is sized from 10 to 100 connections based on your `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`. 100 is a lot of connections. If you opened 100 connections it means that you are:

1. Not closing `Connection` objects once acquired from the pool. A `Connection` object must be closed so the pool can reuse it. One way to ensure `close()` being callied is to always use `try-with-resource`:

   ```
   try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Opening all of them in a short period of time that you don't get the chance to trigger 30 sec timeout (e.g. `maxWait=30000` option that you set). `Connection` objects are meant to be reused, see [HikariCP wiki: About Pool Sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Unfortunately the only way to tell what's happening is to debug the application and see why are you running out of the connections.

Comment: I'm not using the connections directly from the pool. I'm using MyBatis and `JdbcTokenStore`.